# Get CUIDs of all the reports

Tags: java, business-objects, webi

How can I capture CUIDs of all reports available in CMC (Central management Console) or WEBI tool and paste it in Excel?

Manually I can check by viewing each report properties but if I want all the CUID to be captured through coding, is that possible?

Can this be done in Java language?

Comment: There is a free utility from Biclever called [CMS Query Builder](http://biclever.com/software/cms-query-builder/) that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not mine, but hope it can help you :

Here is the sample Java code to export a Web Intelligence document to CSV format.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Document {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

            URL url = new URL(

                    “http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/7485/dataproviders/DP0/flows/0“);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod(“GET”);

            conn.setRequestProperty(“Accept”, “text/plain”);//change to text/plain if you want in CSV format

            String logonToken = “\”” + getLogonToken() + “\””;

            conn.setRequestProperty(“X-SAP-LogonToken”, logonToken);

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {

                throw new RuntimeException(“Failed : HTTP error code : “

                        + conn.getResponseCode());

            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            // Exported CSV file will be generated at “C://rest.csv”, location could be changed as required.
            File f1 = new File(“C://rest.csv”);
            f1.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);//change extension to .csv for csv format

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                bw.write(output);

                bw.write(“\n”);

            }

            bw.close();

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ParseException e) {



            e.printStackTrace();

        }

}

public static String getLogonToken() throws ParseException, IOException {

    String logontoken = null;

    URL url = new URL(“http://localhost:6405/biprws/logon/long/“);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod(“POST”);

    conn.setRequestProperty(“Accept”, “application/json”);

    conn.setRequestProperty(“Content-Type”,

            “application/xml; charset=utf-8”);

    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String body = “<attrs xmlns=\”http://www.sap.com/rws/bip\“>”

            + “<attr name=\”userName\” type=\”string\”>Administrator</attr>”

            + “<attr name=\”password\” type=\”string\”>Password</attr>”

            + “<attr name=\”auth\” type=\”string\” possibilities=\”secEnterprise,secLDAP,secWinAD\”>secEnterprise</attr>”

            + “</attrs>”;

    int len = body.length();

    conn.setRequestProperty(“Content-Length”, Integer.toString(len));

    conn.connect();

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    out.write(body, 0, len);

    out.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {

        throw new RuntimeException(“Failed : HTTP error code : “

                + conn.getResponseCode());

    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String jsontxt = br.readLine();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsontxt);

    logontoken = (String) json.get(“logonToken”);

    conn.disconnect();

    return logontoken;

}

}
```

You can check that too :

https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/13/export-webi-report-using-the-restful-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

BO includes a querying tool called the Query Builder that can be used to extract metadata, such as CUIDs, names, and a lot more.

There is some info [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/17/businessobjects-query-builder-basics/).  To get CUIDs and names, you could use the following simple query:

```
select si_cuid,si_name from ci_infoobjects where si_kind = 'webi'
```