# Retrieve Report details of SAP BO

Tags: java, webi

Using PostMan we can find the data providers, report elements and many more but in this I have to put each Report ID every time to access the report elements, dataset, etc.

Is it possible that without entering report id every time it automatically takes up the report ID of all reports stored in CMC (Central management Console) or WEBI tool of SAP BO?

Can this be done in Java language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get CUIDs of all all the reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299244/get-cuids-of-all-all-the-reports)

Comment: @anjune Hi, i have a similar situation where we have to migrate reports from SAP BO software to PowerBI. I am new to SAP and reports migration, any possible leads if it is achievable via rest api calls or any other method. It would be great if dont have to move data model. Here is my posted question......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776787/how-can-you-migrate-sap-bo-reports-to-powerbi